# Arrow.kt loading state

Tags: android, kotlin, functional-programming, either, arrow-kt

I used `arrow.kt` library so many times, I really enjoyed the features they gave to extend kotlin. I like how `Either<E,T>` can represent the success/failed states seamlessly. I am just wondering if `arrow.kt` has a way to represent loading state along with the other two. In other word, we will have a type that offers three states: `Success`, `Failure`, `Loading`.

I tried to use `Option<T>` as right member, but `None` can't represent loading state as required.

Is there any thing I can try?

Answer (score 1):

`Either<A, B>` represents a single result. You are interested in either the left side or the right side. There's no third.
You could play it in many ways.

1. For example, consider both `Failure` and `Success` as a right result.

```kotlin
sealed interface State {
    object Loading: State

    sealed interface Result: State {
        object Failure: Result
        object Success: Result
    }
}

//...
getState().map { result -> 
    when(result) {
        Failure -> TODO("Handle error")
        Success -> TODO("Handle success")
    }
}.mapLeft { loading -> TODO() }
```

and return `Either<Loading, Result>`.

2. Or have `Either<Loading, Either<Failure, Success>>`

And it is even possible that some kind of subscription to `Flow<State>` or rx `Observable` will suit you more than a single result if you expect to receive multiple responses.